# Grouping transactions by user using EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am using `entity framework core`. (`.net core 2.0`)
I have following `transactions` table structure:

> column: `User1Id` (sent from)
>
> column: `User2Id` (sent to)
>
> column: `Amount`
>
> column: `CreatedAt`

Now, I would like to select all transactions, where either sender or receiver was current user, grouped by users who sent or received the transaction, and only select 15 latest transactions total for each such user.

An example of the output would be (consider current user ID to be 3):

```
[
    {
    "user" = "ID 1 here"
    "transactions" : [
            {
                "User1Id" : "ID of user 3 is either here",
                "User2Id" : "or here",
                "Amount" : 100,
                "CreatedAt" : 10.01.2017
            },{
                "User1Id" : "ID of user 3 is either here",
                "User2Id" : "or here",
                "Amount" : 200,
                "CreatedAt" : 09.01.2017
            }
        ]
    },{
    "user" = "ID 2 here"
    "transactions" : [
            {
                "User1Id" : "ID of user 3 is either here",
                "User2Id" : "or here",
                "Amount" : 100,
                "CreatedAt" : 01.01.2017
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This looks like too complicated query for LINQ.. Nevertheless, here is the closest result I have come up with:

```
var userId = User.GetUserId(); // current user ID
var result = _context.Transactions
   .AsNoTracking()
   .Where(t => t.User1Id == userId || t.User2Id == userId)
   .Select(u => new
   {
       Transaction = u,
       User = (u.User1Id == userId) ? u.User1Id : u.User2Id
   })
   .GroupBy(g => g.User)
   .Select(u => new
   {
       User = u.Key,
       Transaction = u.ToList()
   });
```

First of all - this LINQ produces warning:

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[200500]
>         The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(IIF(([t].User1Id == __userId_2), [t].User1Id, [t].User2Id), new <>f__AnonymousType2`2(Transaction = [t], User = IIF(([t].User1Id == __userId_2), [t].User1Id, [t].User2Id)))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Secondly, There is currently no consideration for ordering of transactions and no limit of how many transactions per user shall be returned.

And lastly, some data is duplicated (such as user ID), because `u.Key.ToList()` is just taking whatever we have value in a previous group by and converting it to list.

I am considering writing a custom SQL for this scenario. Is there a proper LINQ solution?

Answer (score 0):

Would have just made it a comment, but it would have been less understandable in pseudo code.  Sometimes KISS (keep it simple...) is the best way to go.  This is, of course, purely opinion.  For me, I would look into doing something like this:

```
Transactions.Where(t => t.User1Id == userId).Select(t => new { user = t.User2Id, transaction = t})
    .Union(Transactions.Where(t => t.User2Id == userId).Select(t => new { user = t.User1Id, transaction = t }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.transaction.CreatedAt)
    .Take(15)
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => x.user);
```

Comment: this throws an exception `System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Transactions.DAL.Models.Transaction,System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,.......]] _GroupBy[Object,String,<>f__AnonymousType2`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object], System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String], System.Func`2[System.Object,<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,Transactions.DAL.Models.Transaction]])'
Parameter name: arg1`

Comment: I have just read that there is no true support in `entity framework core` for groupby expressions. Is that true? Maybe I should stick to `Dapper`..

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did not test the statement, although it was perhaps presumed.  I edited to add ToList().